# Can istanbul be used to generate HTML report for Code coverage JSON downloaded from Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, istanbul

I am trying use Istanbul and generate HTML report from JSON downloaded using Chrome Dev Tools Protocols.

Getting below error:

"C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\istanbul\lib\object-utils.js:58
Object.keys(statements).forEach(function (st) {
^

TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

JSON is auto generated one, not made any manual edit.

Firstly, is Istanbul can be used to generated HTML report for Coverage JSON from Chrome?

Please let me know if any one had faced issue and able to resolve it.